# EE automatically rewrites URL when trailing slash is missing

Tags: url, rewrite

I noticed that EE rewrites a URL like

`http://www.example.com/parent/child`

(no trailing slash) to

`http://www.example.com/parent/child/?/parent/child`

If I append a trailing slash there is no rewriting.

Initially I assumed it was because for one parent there was a folder of the same name. Then I noticed EE does this for all children (segment_2) if the trailing slash is missing.

How can I prevent this?

I am using EE 2.6.1 with index.php suppressed using the include method, and static Stash cache (https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/Static-cache-setup)

Thank you.

Edit 1: @Robson: Good thought. I totally emptied the template used for www.example.com/parent, and it still happens. The same effect: If I have a trailing slash after "parent" all is ok, if I omit it I get a redirection to www.example.com/parent/?/parent.

Edit 2: After some more investigation I found that the issue is related to my host. It forces query strings, hence I have a "?" after "index.php" in my htaccess file. When I remove the question mark the issue goes away, but now all pages just display "No input file specified". Hmmm...

Comment: How are the `URL`s being output to the front end?